# "Method does not override method from its superclass"

Tags: java, android

can someone help me? I'm new to Android app development and I'm a little confused about how to deal with this error here's my code:

```
public class RegActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText et_email;
private EditText et_password;
private EditText et_name;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private AdView mAdView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   // super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reg);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest1 = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice("A2AA9C5E18C297BBCC0AFCF352517...")
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest1);
    super.onStart();

    et_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_email);
    et_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password);
    et_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_name);

    //findViewById(R.id.b_reg).setOnClickListener();
}

@Override//Here is the error
public void onClick(View view) {

}

public void registration (String email, String password){
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                mAuth.getCurrentUser().sendEmailVerification()
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                    Toast.makeText(RegActivity.this, "Успешная регистрация. Пожалуйста проверьте ваш email, и перейдите по ссылке в письме для верификации.",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    //et_email.setText("");
                                    //et_password.setText("");
                                }else{
                                    Toast.makeText(RegActivity.this,  task.getException().getMessage(),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                Toast.makeText(RegActivity.this, "Регистрация успешна, теперь войдите", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else{
                Toast.makeText(RegActivity.this, "Регистрация провалена", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

Just like this. Can you help?
And that's a mistake:`Method does not override method from its superclass`
Sorry for the translation if something is not clear I'm just from Russia)

Comment: There's no `onClick(View)` method in `AppCompatActivity` for you to override. Did you mean to create an `OnClickListener`?

Comment: The other thing is that you have to uncomment `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` if you will go to Activity.java and see the `onCreate` method that you will see it has annotation `CallSuper` that means that each class that extends this one and override it has to call this method in overrided body function

Comment: I recently started programming and say their language) When you press the button, performed some action, it seemed to me that it is.....

Comment: @Ikazuchi Maybe I somehow not so understood but in `onCreate` there is no `CallSuper``@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        super.onStart();`

Comment: @Antoxa421 and there should be, and remove `super.onStart();` from `onCreate`, do not mix that things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to implement the `OnClickListener` to override that method.

Modify this line:

`public class RegActivity extends AppCompatActivity {`

with this

`public class RegActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {`

Comment: You're not implementing the `OnClickListener` interface in `RegActivity`. That's why it shows the error `Method does not override method from its superclass`. You need to implement the listener as I told you in my post to solve the error.

Comment: I did so `public class RegActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener `And I stopped glowing red `Onclicklistener`

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement View.OnClickListener to override OnClick method, 
You can read more about handling click events here, 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/handling-click-events-button-android/

Answer (score 0):

You are not implementing `View.OnClickListener`.

Change

```
public class RegActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

To

```
public class RegActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
```

This why you will be able to override `onClick`

Answer (score 0):

check import lines of your activity, if the below line is there

`import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;`

then **remove it** and **type** instead of that

`import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;`

because in my case , it worked.